# How to extends class from another package in android studio - java

Tags: java, inheritance, package

I'm trying to inherit a Java class from a different package with a different path in Android Studio(2 different projects).

it's a little bit more complex than the questions I found here.
this is a clean dir tree to demonstrate my project dir:
[image]

this is the proj dir with depth of 4 (projA=pubLeague, projB=externalGames:
[image]

I want to pass `FirebaseFirestore` obj to the games to sync with realtime database tree.

the father class:

```
package android.packName.com;

public class TheFather extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected FirebaseFirestore mDB;
    ...
}
```

for the following code in "TheSon" from the path above, I get "can not resolve symbol 'TheFather'"

```
package android.packageName;

public class GetPlayersActivity extends TheFater {
    ...
}
```

so my 2 questions is:

1. can `TheSon` inherit from `TheFather`?
2. if the answer is yes, how?

Comment: Answer to your question is Yes.

Comment: now I have 2 questions

Comment: How -> TheSon extends TheFather

Comment: "can not resolve symbol 'TheFather'"

Comment: There is no problem asking basic questions, but provide enough information as well.  Paste your code, pasted exact compilation error, etc. or people are not going to look at such questions.

Comment: I just tried to remove any unrelevant info.
the compilation error is "can not resolve symbol 'TheFather'" if I try to extend "TheFather" class because it's in 2 different projects but I can not move one file to the other proj. moreover, this is in Android Studio and one app activity shoul call the TheSon activity.
I will edit my question now

Comment: You may want to read my previous comment one more time

Comment: Now it is clear, earlier comments were on basis of different package not projects. In case of different projects you need to use projA as dependency(library ) in projB.